# Get exact syntax of javascript base functions

Tags: javascript, file, function

Is there a way to know how test (for regex) or cos (for math) or substring (for string) or splice (for array) have been coded in the exact syntax either by a way in Javascript (like `alert(function)`) or by seeking in the files that come with Firefox?

Comment: Cant make sense of your question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You're saying you want to see the implementation of native JavaScript methods? You'd need to view the source files. This is possible with open source implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These functions are actually implemented differently by browsers in one of the OS native languages.

So these algorithms are written in c, c++, c#, java etc. but not in JavaScript.

Comment: If this post answered your question, please select it as answer

Answer (score 1):

Well, the source code of javascript likely isn't written in javascript itself, so you would be unable to just print it to the browser console or alert.

You can browse the source code of google's V8 engine, and see if it helps you ;)

http://code.google.com/p/v8/